# How do I select previous cousin in same position?

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I have an xml document with a section roughly like this:

```
<a>
  <b></b>
  <b>Previous</b>
  <b></b>
  ...
</a>
<a>
  <b></b>
  <b>Current</b>
  <b></b>
  ...
</a>
...
```

I have the following section in my xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//a"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//a">
  <xsl:for-each select="./b[text() != ???]">
  ...
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I need the ??? to select the "c" element that is in the same position (within its parent "a" element) as the current "c" but in the previous "a" element (an example pair are marked as Current and Previous in the xml source).

Essentially this requires passing the position() of the for-each loop to its own select statement. This sounds kind of impossible - as the select statement is only evaluated once.

Now it would be possible to pass the position() from within the for-each loop and save it to a variable which could then be used in an if statement. However, the snag is I want to know when the last iteration has taken place. If I use an if statement then this breaks the meaning of last() - if the last iteration fails the if test.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/b[ text() != ../../preceding-sibling::a/b[position(.)] ]" >
```

the preceding-sibling:: axis selects the node before the current step

Comment: Getting the preceding-sibling as you suggest is quite straightforward but not a complete solution - what would be needed in this instance is ../preceding-sibling::b[the position of the node that for clarity I have labelled with the value "Current" but could in fact be any value]. This is not as straightforward...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that the XPath code was not shown (I forget to mark it as code). I hope now appears ok.

Comment: This results in the following error:
Message: Expected token ')' found '.'. /b[ text() != ../../preceding-sibling::a/b[position(-->.<--)] ]
I didn't think that position() took arguments. The following does not work either ./position(). Using [position()] evaluates to the position of preceding-sibling::a/b node, so that is no use.

I have overcome the issue for my project by a complete rethink and rewrite but I am curious to see if there is a solution to the original problem.